# log in to a custom vf page from a default community login page

Tags: community

I have created a community

I want to log in to a custom vf page from a default community login page

But I am redirected to a default community landing page whenever I login through the default community login page .

Is it possible to redirect to a custom vf page from community login page without redirecting to the community landing page.Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You can change the community Home Page from All Communities > Manage > Administration > Pages, select your Visualforce page here. So once you login to the community this Visualforce page will appear as your new home page.

[image]